# Words with friends receiving extra points not earned

Tags: words-with-friends

My friend's tiles do not add up to their value when she enters a word. She receives more points than the tiles' value. For example, she got 40pt for Zap, with 'Z' on a TL tile only.

It keeps happening. Is this possible?

Comment: Be nice now @RandomDuck.NET. It's not a stupid question. She might not be aware of all the scoring rules. However, I do agree with that a screenshot would help as the OP did not supply enough information for us determine how the 40 points were achieved.

Comment: You may visit the support site of Words with Friends so you can clarify this matter. I also agree with the earlier comments, if you have screenshots so we can identify the problem. Reading the [Game Rules](http://www.wordswithfriends.com/rules.html) will also help.

Answer (score 3):

Was ZAP the first word played in the game? If not it had to connect to another word, and you get points for that connecting word.

ZAP should be worth 14 points.  10 for Z, 1 for A, 3 for P.  With Z on a triple letter tile, you are looking at 34 points.

The other 6 points almost certainly come from the words ZAP connected to.  For instance, if OUR was on the board (3 points) and ZAP was played such that the Z was on a triple letter, and the P landed in front of OUR, you would get 34 points for ZAP, and 6 points for POUR, for a total of 40 points.

Like So:
Z
A
P O U R

The full rules for scoring in Words with friends can be found [here](http://www.wordswithfriends.com/rules.html) but basically, you get points for any words you create, but special tiles only get used the first time they are covered up.  If your friend puts PED after ZAP, she gets 20 points, not 40.